# How can I make the Fluent API for Apache Http Components not base64 encode the body of an HTTP POST?

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

I am using the Apache Http Components Fluent API.

```
Response postResponse = Request.Post(myUrl).bodyString(myJson, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON).execute();
```

It works very well, but it sends the HTTP Body using base64 encoding. I would prefer that it send the body in plain text. Can I make the Fluent API use plain text instead of base64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure HC does not BASE64 encode body content set with `Request#bodyString`. I suspect there might be some other issue or a misunderstanding on your part.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there was a bug in the receiving application! HttpComponents was not doing any encoding (as oleg stated). The receiving application [had a bug](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/issues/browse/MIRTH-2896) which was base64 encoding any `application` MIME types it received. I mistakenly believed that this was being done by HttpComponents.

Both HttpComponents logging and a simple packet sniffer shows that the content was NOT base64 encoded on the wire.

Comment: You are wrong. HC does not do BASE64 content encoding automatically

Comment: Based on my observations, I am seeing base64 encoding output from the first case and not from the second. The receiving application I was sending got what looked like base64 encoded JSON from the first example but not from the second.

I also do not see any obvious calls to base64 encode the data in the HC source code for the first call. I'd love to find out whats really going on here. Can you offer anything more specific?

Comment: The key difference between `ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON` and `ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN` is the charset. I see where @oleg is coming from, theres nothing here that would indicate that HC is doing base64 encoding but I'm sure thats what I saw.  http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.1/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.java

Comment: HttpClient is designed to be content agnostic. It expects the caller to provide content encoded appropriately along with a corresponding ContentType value. Whatever you are seeing is probably an effect of another issue. You can see the _exact_ composition of HTTP messages generated and received by HC by turning on wire logging http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html

Comment: @oleg - Thanks for sticking with this. You were 100% correct the encoding was happening in the receiving application not in my code nor in HttpComponents. The receiving application had a bug which was encoding all `application` MIME types in base64. Looking at both a packet sniffer and HttpComoponents logging showed non-encoded content on the wire. Bug description for the receiving application: http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/issues/browse/MIRTH-2896